# URL does not in IE11 but it does work in IE10

Tags: utf-8, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I've found an issue when accessing to an URL related to special characters. The URL is generated in JS with many parameters. When the redirection is processed in IE10 the URL works fine. This is the parameter with the special character and that causes the problem:

> nacional=Espa%C3%B1a

but when the same process is executed in IE11 the same parameter looks like this. As you can see it is not encoded in UTF-8

> nacional=EspaÃ±a

I've tried to change in IE the encoding and the UTF-8 link properties and it didn't work.

Comment: It depends on URL values representation for Unicode symbols, in IE11 it's UTF-8; in IE11< - ISO... Check: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2014/04/22/unicode-in-url-changes-for-ie11/

Comment: I've alredy checked that post. If it helps in Chrome it does work too